# Can anyone explain why my footer won't stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have tried all the things that you get when looking up how to make a footer stick to the bottom. Right now it is just pushed to the bottom with padding. I have to rebuild the google homepage for a school project and my code is on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h19q7ojw/) Any help would be appreciated.

```
Because it is required
```

Comment: show code here! not just on a fiddle.

Comment: I though the ink to fiddle would be better as it was the code for the whole page

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future. The absence of relevant code in your question makes it much less useful for the future (and that link will die at some point, which makes it useless too).

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed`, not `position: absolute`.

`position: absolute` is not absolutely absolute... It's relative to the nearest non-statically-positioned parent (often an element with `position: relative`). I'm sure it made sense to someone at some point.

In order to make it stick relative to browser window, you need `position: fixed`

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h19q7ojw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Because some other browsers have margin on the `body` by default.

To remove it add it on your css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body has got 8px margin, remove it and it should be ok.